# Interrogative negative in conditional sentence

Tags: conditionals

What will this sentence imply -

> Wouldn't it have been better if you had come earlier?

As we know the negative form of this sentence will imply that "it was better" but it wouldn't have been if certain necessary requirements hadn't been fulfilled .

Comment: With the comma in place, it doesn’t really imply anything. There’s some kind of a wish and half a conditional, with a comma in between.

Comment: So if comma is removed then what will it imply

Comment: Then it might be a reprimand or perhaps a wistful statement. Commas aren’t always significant, but in this case it is. Please [edit] your question so that it reflects the question you’d like to find answers for.

Comment: For example if i write " Wouldn't it have been amazing if you had come home earlier " , Does this imply that "it wasn't amazing since you didn't come home earlier " ?

Comment: Possibly. A lot depends on context, including tone of voice, whether this is a parent talking to a child, whether there was a smile etc. It’s like saying “this number is not positive” - you know it’s not as good, but you don’t know the extent. Worse, if this was spoken sarcastically, the intent could even go the other way.

Comment: Thanks for editing.

Comment: Thanks for the response